# How do I override a block in a nested template in Twig 2.x

Tags: twig

I'm trying to override a block in a nested template, but I can't figure out how it's done.

See my problem at [TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/wict38).

The `myblock`is correctly overridden to show `custom myblock`, but the `nestedblock` won't be overridden, and I can't figure out how to do it.

Can anybody give some good pointers? :)

Actual output:

```
Hi 

    custom myblock 

    nestedblock
```

Expected output:

```
Hi 

    custom myblock 

    custom nestedblock
```

Comment: Please add your code directly inside your question. What you are trying to do is not possible in `twig`. See the linked question. Perhaps you could solve it by using the [`use`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/use.html) tag, but that depends on your use-case

Comment: Thansk for your answers and comments - I found out that I had missed some core points in how Twig worked :)